# Ext.Net Control visibility

Tags: javascript, events, code-behind, ext.net

I have a ext:Button and ext:GridPanel on my page that default visibility for my ext:GridPanel is false.I want to set ext:GridPanel visibility to true by clicking on ext:Button.How can I perform this action?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `.Visible` property, please use the `.Hidden` property. Setting `Hidden="true"` on initial page_load, then during the DirectEvent/DirectMethod, set `.Hidden=false`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's Geoffrey, but I use a PagingToolBar in my ext:GridPanel, when I set the Hidden value of ext:GridPanel to true and again set to false, the PagingToolBar doesn't display.